# C# Marshaling, ubalanced stack and getting PInvoke signature correct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to call a C DLL in my C# project using marshaling and have some functions working but I have trouble with others. Like the one below.

My first problem is getting the structs correct and next problem is to return PROFILE_INFO as an array with the list of program files or maybe it won't return a list and proNum is an index.

function in C

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI GetProgramFileList (unsigned long proNum, PROFILE_INFO *proFile);

typedef struct{
    PROINFO         proInfo;
    __int64             proSize;
    PROGRAM_DATE    createDate;
    PROGRAM_DATE    writeDate;
}PROFILE_INFO;

typedef struct{
    char wno[33];
    char dummy[7];
    char comment[49];
    char dummy2[7];
    char type;
    char dummy3[7];
}PROINFO;

typedef struct{
    short   year;
    char    month;
    char    day;
    char    hour;
    char    min;
    char    dummy[2];
}PROGRAM_DATE;
```

My function

```
[DllImport(@".\IFDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProgramFileList", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetProgramFileListTest(ulong proNum, ref PROFILE_INFO pro);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct PROFILE_INFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public PROINFO proInfo;            // WNo/name/type
    public long proSize;               // Program size
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public PROGRAM_DATE createDate;    // Program creating date
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public PROGRAM_DATE writeDate;     // Program updating date
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct PROINFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string wno;         // WNo.
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy;       // dummy
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 49)] public string comment;     // program name
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy2;      // dummy
    public char type;                                                               // program type
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy3;      // dummy
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct PROGRAM_DATE
{
    public short year;                 // Date (Year) 4-digit
    public char month;                 // Date (Month)
    public char day;                   // Date (Day)
    public char hour;                  // Date (Time)
    public char min;                   // Date (Minutes)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)] private char dummy; // Dummy
}
```

The PROGRAM_DATE createDate in C# struct PROFILE_INFO will throw:

> Cannot marshal field 'createDate' of type 'CClient.Models.PROFILE_INFO': The type definition of this field has layout information but has an invalid managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable.

Changing PROGRAM_DATE fields to string makes it accept it but the function returns an argument(-60) error instead. Though not sure if I'm closer to success.

Other attempts, including attempts to get PROFILE_INFO to return as an array (ref PROFILE_INFO[]), landed in:

> A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.

I have got these descriptions following the C dll:

> ## Explanation
>
> Obtain the program list in the standard area
>
> ## Argument
>
> > proNum [in]
> >
> > Specify the number of the data to be obtained.
> >
> > proFile [out]
> >
> > Store the program information in the standard area, in PROFILE_INFO type.
>
> Before executing this function, make sure to ensure the data area for the number of the data to be obtained.
>
> ## Return value
>
> If it succeeded, “0” is returned. If there is an error, a value other than “0” is returned.

Other functions I have working is GetProgramDirInfo, SendProgram, ReceiveProgram, SearchProgram, etc. but they don't return any arrays, so I assume marshaling arrays is my problem here. Also I'm trying to avoid using unsafe pointers and I'm unsure if I need to do the copying myself.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points when working with p/invoke:

- don't add what's obvious for .NET (structs are structs, ...)
- don't add `pack` if you're unsure, by default .NET should behave like C/C++ on that matter
- don't add Ansi information if there's no string in the definition (only when there are strings or TStr, etc.). It doesn't cause problems but is useless
- in general, don't add attributes if you don't know what they are used for
- `int` and `long` in C/C++ are (in general) 32-bit. `long` is not 64-bit in C/C++

Here is a code that should be better:

```
  [DllImport(@".\IFDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProgramFileList")]
  public static extern int GetProgramFileListTest(uint proNum, ref PROFILE_INFO pro);

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct PROFILE_INFO
  {
      public PROINFO proInfo;            // WNo/name/type
      public long proSize;               // Program size
      public PROGRAM_DATE createDate;    // Program creating date
      public PROGRAM_DATE writeDate;     // Program updating date
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
  public struct PROINFO
  {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)] public string wno;         // WNo.
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy;       // dummy
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 49)] public string comment;     // program name
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy2;      // dummy
      public char type;                                                               // program type
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)] private string dummy3;      // dummy
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
  public struct PROGRAM_DATE
  {
      public short year;                 // Date (Year) 4-digit
      public char month;                 // Date (Month)
      public char day;                   // Date (Day)
      public char hour;                  // Date (Time)
      public char min;                   // Date (Minutes)
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)] private string dummy; // Dummy
  }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that was a great help.. 
I managed to get data back if I set proNum = 1 but not if I set proNum >= 2
Shouldn't it return an array ?

Comment: @KimJensen - it depends what you do in your C/C++ code

Comment: The name and description hints at a "list", is it right to assume it will return an array size of proNum ?
If proNum is an index the proNum = 2 it should give me some data, since GetProgramDirInfo tells me totalProNum = 56, but it crashes.

Comment: If it's an array, try to define the function as `GetProgramFileListTest(uint proNum, [In, Out] PROFILE_INFO[] pro)` and pass `pi` where `var pi = new PROFILE_INFO[2]` for example